# Facing difficulty in pagination using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am showing results arranged in table from mysql database using php, but I am not being able to find a way to paginate my results, because of the data being arranged in table and because some of the rows are missing and as webpage will be dynamic so user will be able to delete rows and insert new rows again and again, so because of that I can't get my results paginated using `auto_increment` value as well.

Following is my script:

```
<?php
    $mysql_session = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM session");
    $no_of_rows_session = mysql_num_rows($mysql_session);
    $msg_session='';
    $last_row = mysql_query("SELECT * from session ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    $last_id = '';

    while($select_id_of_last_row = mysql_fetch_array($last_row)) {
        $last_id = $select_id_of_last_row['id'];
    }
?>



<?php echo $msg_session; ?>
<?php
    if($no_of_rows_session < 1) {
        $msg_session = 'No Session has been added yet';
    } else {
        for($i = 1; $i<=$last_id; $i++) {                   
            ${'mysql_session_every_single_query_' . $i} = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM session WHERE id LIKE '%$i%'");
            ${'mysql_existance_of_session_id_' . $i} = mysql_num_rows(${'mysql_session_every_single_query_' . $i});
            while(${'mysql_every_session_data_' . $i} = mysql_fetch_array(${'mysql_session_every_single_query_' . $i})){
                ${'id_session_' . $i} = ${'mysql_every_session_data_' . $i}['id'];
                ${'session_start_' . $i} = ${'mysql_every_session_data_' . $i}['start'];
                ${'session_end_' . $i} = ${'mysql_every_session_data_' . $i}['end'];
                echo "<table>";
                    echo "<tr id='tr_session_hover_" . $i . "'
                                class='tr_session_hover' 
                                onClick=\"document.location='session_edit.php?ss=${'session_start_' . $i}&se=${'session_end_' . $i}';\">
                            <td>" . ${'session_start_' . $i} . "-" . ${'session_end_' . $i} . "</td>
                        </tr>";
                echo "</table>";
            }
        }

    }     
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using variable variables everywhere?

Comment: I am going to use these variable variables in another script by GET method. I have also found a way to paginate the results, i will answer this question once i confirm that the method i am thinking works.

Comment: Would it not be more wise to create an array with all the data stored about each iteration instead of creating how ever many dynamic variables?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but shouldn't the echo <table> and </table> lines be on the outside of your loop?

Comment: Thanks for trying to guide me @Bankzilla sir (for edit also), but array can't provide me what i need to do in the next script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a solution.
If you are also facing such kind of problem and want to proceed with variables only (like me):

suppose you need to show 6 results on one page and your auto_increment (suppose a column named id is the auto_increment one, in your table) values are't regular, then what you can do is, get id of the 6th element by

I am supposing that you have already connected to phpmyadmin and selected a database

```
$no_of_results_per_page = 6;

if(isset($_GET['page_no'])) {
  $page_no = $_GET['page_no']; 
} else{
  $page_no = 1;

}


  $upper_limit = ($page_no - 1)*$no_of_result_per_page - 1;

if($page_no > 1){
  $mysql_getting_id_le = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table LIMIT $upper_limit, 1");

  while($getting_id_last_elem = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_getting_id_le)) {
    $id_last_element = $getting_id_last_elem['id'];
  }
} else {
  $mysql_getting_id_le = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 0, 1");

  while($getting_id_last_elem_p_1 = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_getting_id_le)) {
    $id_last_element = $getting_id_last_elem_p_1['id'];
$id_last_element = $id_last_element - 1;
  }
}
```

The above query will help us in getting id of the last element of the page

Now we will be creating the buttons to navigate from one page to another.

```
$final_mysql_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > '%id_last_element%' LIMIT $no_of_results_per_page");

//Now, we can get all data limited to show no. of results you have defined per page using a loop

$total_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

$total_results_count = mysql_num_rows($total_results);

$total_pages = ceil($total_results_count/$no_of_results_per_page);

$page_no = '';

for($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
  $page_no .= "<a href='?page_no=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on wrong way. The things like this is simple when you choice the some order criteria and implement it into your table - for example the time of last edit or creation of the row. After that, when you have a page length and number of the page you have to use OFFSET / LIMIT clauses for SELECT, ordered by criteria - in this way you let the MySQL engine generate the proper pages.

Comment: sorry sir but I am in the right direction for what I am willing to achieve.